# errors in encoding avc x264 to av1 using latest ffmpeg libaom linux

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, git, video-encoding

I have a system with Intel i3 10th generation processor and Asus H510 me motherboard. I have installed Arch Linux x86_64 latest version and after that I have installed `aom` package from official repository and after that I have compiled `ffmpeg` with option `--enable-libaom`.

I am getting errors while using ffmpeg from command line.

For the last year I have been using `ffmpeg` along with `libaom` and I have not encountered any error. Yesterday I removed the aom package from my system and after that I uninstalled `ffmpeg`.

I then reinstalled `aom` package and then compiled the source code of `ffmpeg` with option `--enable-libaom` and it succeeded. Here the issue is when I want to convert a h264 avc .mp4 video file to av1 but I am getting error as follows.

```
Overriding packet duration by frame rate, this should not happen
```

After that I removed the `aom` package and uninstalled `ffmpeg`. After that I have tried to install aom-git aur package using yay helper and succeeded. Now I have tried to compile source code of `ffmpeg` with option `--enable-libaom` and again it succeeded. After that I have tried to convert h264 avc .mp4 video file using ffmpeg but again I am getting same error as follows.

```
Overriding packet duration by frame rate, this should not happen
```

From the past one year I have not received any such errors but now I am getting. Previously I have used ffmpeg along with Linux distributions Fedora 36 debian stable etc.,.

5 days back the package installed from aom-git aur repository worked fine along with ffmpeg but now can't.

Finally I have compiled the source code of aom downloaded from git official repository as mentioned in itself but still I am getting same error.

Previously as I have not received any errors and now I think that there's a bug in the source code of aom git repository.

If you want I will provide another output of the commands specified by you. Kindly try to suggest how to make ffmpeg with libaom run properly without any errors in my arch Linux system.

Comment: I see the same errors, but only if I choose ".mp4" as a target container. When I use ".mkv", there are no errors reported. Perhaps choosing a different container format could be some workaround for some of us.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the bug is within the code of latest ffmpeg from git.

I have compiled the source code of ffmpeg which was pulled from git one month ago. There are no errors while compiling the source code. Even there are no errors while converting x264 to av1.